# how can I get View from another view

Tags: java, android

here is my xml file

```
             <FrameLayout 
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 >
                 <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/productButton_download"
                    android:onClick="testGetView"
                     />

                 <ProgressBar
                     style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                     android:layout_width="50dp"
                     android:layout_height="30dp"
                     android:visibility="invisible"
                      />
             </FrameLayout>
```

I want get the ProgressBar instance use the function testGetView instead of get it use a resource id

```
public void testGetView(View button) {
    // what can I do use this view to get the progressbar below it

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to set an id to your `ProgressBar`, then from your button, get its parent view with `getParent()`, cast it to `ViewGroup` and then call `findViewById(int id)` with the id of your `ProgressBar`

Comment: thanks a lot , I use getParent() cast to View and find it ,now I can get it in each row